# How to place vertical scrollbar of textView from right to left?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, textview

I applied vertical scrollbar on my textview in an android app but it is by default showing at the right side of the textview. I want to move it (place it) to the left side of the textView. here is the code, please tell what modification needed:

```
TextView abc.setText("sfihogwhgo \n lwhgieowehgwegoihwgoe \n wfeliwegh \n woihgi");
 abc.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Also, in the layout xml:

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_ghazal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="514dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="20sp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                />
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do this, one is through xml:

```
android:verticalScrollbarPosition="left"
```

or through Java code:

```
abc.setVerticalScrollbarPosition(View.SCROLLBAR_POSITION_LEFT);
```